# How do I pull data to a new sheet between dates and searches for a string/value in a cell and only prints rows with the specified string

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to pull data from one sheet to another based on a range of dates specified by user input. I also want to specify to only pull the rows if a cell has a certain string value. The string value is either Hot, Warm, or Cold.

```
TextBox1 takes the first date 

TextBox2 takes the second date
```

When the button is clicked,
the sheet then takes data from the "Raw Data" and prints to to the sheet "Selected Data"

Here's what the form looks like:

[image: Form]

This is how the data looks like:

[image: Raw Data]

For example: How do I pull the data between January 1st 2019 - December 31st 2019 (User inputted dates) that only have the heat value as Hot.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, x As Date, y As Date, erow As Long

x = TextBox1
y = TextBox2

With Sheets("Raw Data")
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lrow
        If Cells(i, 1) * 1 >= x * 1 Then
            If Cells(i, 1) * 1 <= y * 1 Then
                With Sheets("Selected Data")
                    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                End With
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 12)).Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("Selected Data").Cells(erow, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.List = Array("Hot", "Warm", "Cold", "#N/A")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, this macro will compare the first date and last date then check if its 'Hot' :

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Compteur As Long
    Dim wS As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

    'Here we look in Column A
    LastRow = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Debug.Print LastRow


  For Compteur = 2 To LastRow


    If CDate(Cells(Compteur, 1).Value) < CDate(textbox2) And CDate(Cells(Compteur, 1).Value) > CDate(textbox1) Then
        If Cells(Compteur, 12) = "Hot" Then
            Sheets("Selected Data").Rows(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Selected Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Sheets("Raw Data").Rows(Compteur).Value
        End If

    End If

  Next Compteur



End Sub
```